# android:label property not affecting flutter application name

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

I'm working on a simple flutter application and would like to change the name displayed under the icon, in the launcher. As far as I know this should be done on Android by changing

```
android:label
```

property in AndroidManifest.xml

The only problem is that changing it doesn't have any effect. My apps name is still the project name (eg. test_app).

I've tried typing the name directly into the field and creating another xml file in /android/app/src/main/res/values and reading the name from there. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My awesome app</string>
</resources>
```

and in the Android manifest.xml

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

This didn't help.

Here is everything between the application tags in my AndroidManifest.xml at this point:

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="My awesome app"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also the package_info library gives the original working name (eg. test_app) and not the name I specified  in the android:label.

Should this work when debugging?

Am I missing something basic? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently running the app in release mode did the trick. No idea why but there probably is a good reason for it.